# On the command line how can I tell 7-Zip to disable the new (in 23.00) ARM64 filter?

Tags: 7-zip

### Question

How can I teach 7-Zip -- specifically the command line version `7z` -- that I want to disable only the ARM64 filter, but all others are acceptable?

My goal would now be to disable the ARM64 filter in the newer 7-Zip versions, keeping compatibility with the older 7-Zip versions.

### Background

7-Zip 23.00 introduced the ARM64 filter for binaries targeting the eponymous architecture. Excerpt from the [history.txt](https://www.7-zip.org/history.txt):

> ##### 23.00          2023-05-07
>
> - 7-Zip now can use new ARM64 filter for compression to 7z and xz archives.   ARM64 filter can increase compression ratio for data
>   containing executable   files compiled for ARM64 (AArch64)
>   architecture.   Also 7-Zip now parses executable files (that have exe
>   and dll filename extensions)   before compressing, and it selects
>   appropriate filter for each parsed file:
>
>   - BCJ or BCJ2 filter for x86 executable files,
>   - ARM64 filter for ARM64 executable files.   Previous versions by default used x86 filter BCJ or BCJ2 for all exe/dll files.

This effectively introduces a backward incompatibility. Whenever asking older versions of 7-Zip to process a file created with version 23.00 or newer *and* containing an ARM64 binary, the output will look something like:

```
Method = 0A LZMA2:26 LZMA:20 BCJ2 ARMT
```

... whereas with the new versions we can see that `0A` translates to `ARM64`:

```
Method = ARM64 LZMA2:26 LZMA:20 BCJ2 ARMT
```

### What I have tried & "benchmarks"

While with `-mf=BCJ2` I can tell it to use *exclusively* the specified filter or with `-mf=off` I can turn all filters off, neither seems to be what I want. Turning off all filters means worse compression ratio. Turning on only a particular filter *everywhere* means slower compression.

Comparison (file system cache was prepopulated for all of the tests):

- switches as previously: yield `Method = ARM64 LZMA2:26 LZMA:20 BCJ2 ARMT`, in 36.620 s and a size of 115454049 bytes (111 MiB)

  - `-t7z -mx=9 -myx=7 -mmt=on -mmtf=on -ms=on -mqs=on -mtm=off -mtc=off -mta=off -mtr=off -stl`
- with additional `-mf=off`: yields `Method = LZMA2:26`, in 37.692 s and a size of 116861788 bytes (112 MiB)
- with additional `-mf=BCJ2`: yields `Method = LZMA2:26 LZMA:20 BCJ2`, in 36.031 s and a size of 115483281 bytes (111 MiB)

Obviously for my example -- which is a smaller subset of what I am actually trying -- the size and performance difference between `-mf=BCJ2` and without is small enough. But for the actual size of data I am working with we're getting into regions where these sum up.